# How to create an SQL stored procedure to insert multiple values

Tags: mysql, sql, stored-procedures, amazon-rds

I have the following statement which takes an array of values and stores them in my MySQL RDS:

```
INSERT INTO items (item_id, item_name, item_description) VALUES ?
```

I am using this with AWS Appsync which does not provide an escaping mechanism to prevent injection, so I would like to use a stored procedure in my RDS for security against [injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection).

This statement will be used to create multiple items, so an array of values will be passed in.

How could I create a stored procedure to insert multiple values into a table? I was referred to the following example for a select statement with a single argument, but I am not sure how I can apply this to a more complex case with multiple arguments as in my above statement.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE listPets (IN type_param VARCHAR(200))
  BEGIN
     PREPARE stmt FROM 'SELECT * FROM Pets where type=?';
     SET @type = type_param;
     EXECUTE stmt USING @type;
     DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
  END
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
CREATE PROCEDURE listPets (IN p_itemid INT, IN p_itemname VARCHAR(200), 
      IN p_itemdesc VARCHAR(200))
BEGIN
    PREPARE stmt FROM 'INSERT INTO items (item_id, item_name, item_description) VALUES (?, ?, ?)';
    SET @id = p_itemid, @name = p_itemname, @description = p_itemdesc;
    EXECUTE stmt USING @id, @name, @description;
    DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
END
```

Refer to docs on [PREPARE](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/prepare.html) and [EXECUTE](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/execute.html).

Tip: You might like to use this alternative INSERT syntax:

```
PREPARE stmt FROM 'INSERT INTO items SET item_id=?, item_name=?, item_description=?';
```

It's MySQL's nonstandard extension to SQL, to make it easier to match up the columns and `?` placeholders. But it doesn't support multi-row inserts.

Comment: I need to use multi-row inserts.  just wondering how to pass the array of values into this prepare statement using the format you outlined above

Comment: MySQL doesn't have an array type. Stored procedures can only take a fixed set of scalar arguments. But I'm not sure why you say Appsync doesn't support parameterized INSERT, I found an example on this blog: https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/mobile/aws-appsync-adds-support-for-sql-databases-with-amazon-aurora-connector/

Comment: I was using that exact variable mapping from your link but speaking with their support rep he said that that format doesn't sanitize against injection.  I'm mainly a front end programmer and not too familiar.  He referred me to the following link: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/appsync/latest/devguide/tutorial-rds-resolvers.html#input-sanitazation

Comment: Wow, that's pretty disappointing. Appsync: *insecure by design.* If it were me, it would be enough to make me drop Appsync like a hot potato and use some other language or platform.

Comment: I was thinking to change to a nosql design like DynamoDB but with all my relations I think that is going to set me back quite a long way.  they say this Appsync RDS combo is Beta so I am hoping they will add better security going forward.  For now I may just use a lambda node function to prepare my sql statements and pass to the Appsync resolver.  I guess it will slow things down a bit but maybe lessen the complexity

Comment: Yes, my understanding of DynamoDB is that it's a key-value store. It's good if you have a large number of discrete data that you want to query by key only. Not good for the kinds of set-oriented queries you'd do with SQL. I still find SQL to be more general-purpose than any NoSQL solution. Every brand of NoSQL optimizes for a certain query type, at the expense of all other query types.

Answer (score 0):

If you meant to update an existing record:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE LIST_Pets
(
    --These are the Variables/columns you need to enter data into to update
    @item_name VARCHAR(15),
    @item_description VARCHAR(30),

    --These are the variables used to get the correct record which needs update
    @item_id INT
)
AS
BEGIN
UPDATE TABLE type_param
SET item_name = ISNULL(item_name, @item_name)--if the item_name is null it will insert @item_name
SET item_description = ISNULL(item_description, @item_description)
WHERE item_id = @item_id
```